# Select 1st 6 months records from a table when the date columns datatype in varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I wanted to select the 1st 6 months result from below given table. The problem is months field has store as string(Varchar2) using '2016 DEC' this format. I'm using oracle 12c.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just convert to a date:

```
where to_date(col, 'YYYY-MON') < date '2016-07-01'
```

Or, if you want this dynamic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(to_date(col, 'YYYY-MON')) over () as min_date
      from t
     ) t
where date < add_months(min_date, 6);
```

Comment: Gordon has given you the best technical answer for your situation, but we'd be remiss if we did not point out that storing dates as anything other than a DATE datatype is a very serious design failure.  In your case it appears that the designer was trying to map the table directly to the needs of one particular report instead of following sound design principles and then having each report format the data as needed.